# Amd HD 6850M, Acer 7750G driver issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, intel-graphics, hybrid

I have the configuration mentioned in the title.

**To name the exact problem :**

I wanted to be a full Linux convert from windows. Bought very fast laptop but did not check graphics compatibility. Now after installing the proprietary driver from ati (amd) on **Ubuntu 10.10** gives me **"not supported" watermark** on the right bottom. After checking some forums (google is your best friend) I discovered that my lap has 2 graphic cards, amd hd 6850m and intel hd3000 as secondary.

Also, after installing this driver It slows down my graphics (so **slower** as with the default open source).

**My question**:

1. **Is there any way to unleash the potential of my graphics with this proprietary driver?**
2. **Is using the open source drivers the only option?**

I don't think the actual ati graphic card is used, but the intel3000 by mistake.

PS: Natty gives no better results

Edit 15.12.2011 : It works, it works !!! I`m so happy :)

1. Installed build-essential
2. Downloaded the newest catalyst from amd site
3. Ran install sudo sh Amd...xxx.sh
4. Restart

I guess also the install is better to do BEFORE installing pae kernel. Thank you guys

Comment: can you mark this question as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm happy to tell you that the Catalyst 11.9 is in the Ubuntu respos!
Now, you can just install it by the "colsed source drivers" managger.

Note: It's important, that you'll need a **clean install**! That means must not any previos versions of catalyst is installed, or were installed on your system since the last full install. Pleas also note, that you have to install the post-upgrade version of catalyst, and **only** this version. It's also notable that the managger will tell you that "installation failed, please see jockey.log" but **do nothing**, reboot your system, and everything **will** work fine.

Comment: I installed the upper one from additional drivers (post release updates). Now again having unsupported hardware watermark in the bottom left and graphics are bad. Secondary monitor cannot change resolution, effects disabled etc

Comment: ~$ glxgears
9081 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1816.049 FPS
8189 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1637.612 FPS
12090 frames in 5.0 seconds = 2417.743 FPS

Comment: Well, I can't say more that it works for me.
Have you had a clean install? I had to do it, to get it work.

I'm really sorry if it not works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> For the question 1.
>
> The newest proprietary driver(**catalyst 11.9**) solves the problem with watermark for AMD 6850M watermark. You can prepare your own fglrx packages with the help of:
> http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide.
> See section **Installing the drivers manually**.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a nother way to fix things - Go to the AMD website, and download the lastest catalyst (11.10). Install it manually.

After a sucesfull install, and a reboot there will be a bug, and the driver won't start.
Go to a terminal prompt (CTRL+ALT+F1) log in and get root rights (sudo -s).

The driver is fails, becaous it searches libGL.so.1 at a wrong place, we'll do a link for it.

```
link /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

(I think, if you have 32-bit system, you'll have to use lib32 instead lib64 in the first path, but I can't test it.)

Set up the fglrx again:

```
aticonfig --initial
```

After that, restart x (or reboot) and everithing should work fine (=works for me).

Note for programmers: In the system preferences, the tab will still say you're using vesa drivers, but that could be a bug. I have good fps (at least 200 at fullscreen) and catalyst center each settings works correctly, and also CPU-stats doesent seems to inercase on graphics movements. (It does it when I use vesa) Even if it works even better for me than by default, I'm not sure it's not vesa: I'm not a developer of any driver, just found a lib which fits to the missing one but it could be different.