# How do I fix lagging windows and remove a graphics card watermark?

Tags: 11.10

So i got some problems with ubuntu on my Acer Aspire 7750G i5 Radeon HD 6650M 4GB Ram 64Bit

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

so my first problem is window dragging; if i drag mozilla or any other windows it gets laggy and the cursor is behind

my seccond problem is how to remove the Hardware is not supported watermark after installing the graphic card drivers

thx for yor help

Comment: You should split this question into two questions.

Answer (score 2):

The Catalyst 11.9 is now in the Ubuntu repos, and you can install it.

Look here: [Amd HD 6850M, Acer 7750G driver issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63890/amd-hd-6850m-acer-7750g-driver-issues/84424#84424)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think, we should report the watermark as a bug.

However the watermark is right, the driver fails back to VESA, so the driver not supports the card, but in previous versions it worked.
Even if the closed-driver not works and not fixable, the Ubuntu shouldn't install it for these computers.

If you just want to remove the watermark, you can use the sript below, but that **wont** fix your problem, your driver **will still** fail back to VESA. It would be even better now to remove the closed driver. 
(Well, in this case the removing of the driver will fail, so you will have to reinstall your system... sorry)

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DRIVER=/usr/lib/fglrx/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
for x in $(objdump -d $DRIVER|awk '/call/&&/EnableLogo/{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6}'); do
 sed -i "s/$x/\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90/g" $DRIVER
done
```